# Getter and Setter methods are not getting generated - Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Getter and Setter methods are not getting generated. We are using Zend framework 2 and Doctrine 2 for web application development.

After executing following command:

`./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities  ./module/Baaqdsttestform27/src/`

It don't show any error also, Can anybody suggest how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't remember but the command maybe is orm:generate:entities ./module/Baaqdsttestform27/src/ , have you enable php errors in cli?

Comment: yes, but no error found.

Comment: Try to read this issue https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6866

Comment: Methods are not generating because of table column names are '100Buy', '50Buy' might that is throwing exception while generating methods. Any solution to avoid this issue ?